# Jquery custom checkboxes and radios not passing value correctly with .val()

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins

I'm using the plugin located here: http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/06/11/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

to style my radio buttons and checkboxes. When I submit the form without using jQuery.get all the values are passed just fine. BUT when I try to extract the value using:

```
   var sort = $('input[name=sort]:checked').val();
```

It doesnt work. It keeps saying "new" no matter whether the "new" radio or "expire" radio are checked. I'm trying to figure out what the hell I'm doing wrong. I also tried extracting the value of the label that gets designated with the class .r_on when the radio button is selected, but I couldn't manage to do that either.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var sort = $('input[name=sort]:checked').val();
var location = $('#location').val();


$('.filter_submit').click(function(){
    $.get("../bin/open_tasks.php", "sort=" + sort + "&location=" + location , function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });//end get request
    return false;
    });//end click 

});

<fieldset class="radios">
            <label class="label_radio" for="new">Newest<input id="new" checked="checked" class="" type="radio" name="sort" value="new"></label><br>
            <label class="label_radio" for="expire">Expiring First<input id="expire" class="" type="radio" name="sort" value="expire"></label>
        </fieldset>
```

and this is the php i wrote just to test it out:

```
<?php 

    echo "loaded kinda";

    echo " ".$_GET['sort']." ";
    echo $_GET['location'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
        if ($('input[name=sort]').is(':checked')) {
```

instead of this

```
     var sort = $('input[name=sort]:checked').val();
```

EDIT:

what about this

```
        $('input[name=sort]').change(function () {
             //this will fire when radio button is clicked
             //store this information somewhere
           }
```

Comment: It's a radio button. One or the other will always be checked.

I did this for the checkboxes, and they worked just fine.

Comment: I tried and it still only spits "new".

edit: is there a way to get the value of the label instead? It gets designated with a special class when that radio button is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the value on page load (`.ready`). This is too early - it will be the value at that time, which is always the same.

You probably want to get the value when you submit, so that updating the radio button gets you the updated value. Just move the `.val()` line into the `.click` handler. The same goes for the `#location` line.

Comment: Thanks! It's always the stupid little things you facepalm yourself over, isnt it?

Comment: @user1589198: Well, at least you can learn from experiencing something like this :)